# Connecting Funambol to MySQL on remote host

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc, connection, funambol

I am setting up Funambol 8.7 on a Linux host (using Amazon AWS).  I need to connect to a MySQL datbase that is hosted on a different server.

Per the administration guide I went ahead and downloaded the mysql connector and placed the jar in /opt/Funambol/tools/jre-1.6.0/lib/ext.  I changed the install.properties file as follows:

```
  dbms=mysql


  jdbc.classpath=/opt/Funambol/tools/jre-1.6.0/jre/lib/ext/mysql-connector-java-5.1.14-bin.jar
  jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://myserver.net/rugcutte_funambol?characterEncoding=UTF-8
  jdbc.user=rugcutte_funambo
  jdbc.password=funambol
```

THen I try to run the install, but get the following error:

```
/opt/Funambol/ds-server/install/install.xml:452: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'rugcutte_funambo'@'ec2-50-16-233-200.compute-1.amazonaws.com' (using password: YES)
```

It appears my AWS instance can connect successfully to my MySQL database however it is trying to login with a fully qualified user name that is incorrect: rugcutte_funambo'@'ec2-50-16-233-200.compute-1.amazonaws.com

I tried also to change the line to :  jdbc.user=rugcutte_funambo@myserver.net .  But I got a similar error with that as well.

I am relatively inexperienced to JDBC.  What is the proper way to set up this section of the install.properties file?

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable access to that database with that user from that server?

What happens if you try and just make the same mysql connection from the command line from your Funambol server?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Adam.

You led me to the correct answer.  The remote host has an area in cPanel to configure Remote Database Access Hosts.  So I did, need to add my source host that is running Funambol, to my list of access hosts.

After this I ran the install and it did, appear to create the tables properly in the database running on my remote host.